# Recommendation for a configurable Android application that performs a task frequently

Tags: android, service, android-service

I am trying to create an android application that does following:

1. On installation it gives the user a UI where in they are allowed to enter their gmail id/password and twitter id/password.
2. The user then clicks on a button that launches a service that runs in background to check his gmail account for new mail arrival. This service should keep running forever even after the UI(activity) is removed from foreground.
3. If the arrived email is in a specified format, it starts tweeting from his twitter account.
4. The tweets are based on contents of the mail and may be numerous. These tweets go after a certain interval of time, say 3 mins. Hence tweeting task may take hours to complete.(With a phone sleep/restart in between.)
5. The service/background task must be stoppable and resume again in case if the user decided to change his gmail/twitter credentials.

I have implemented the service(Intent service to be more general) which does check the gmail inbox for new mail arrival. But some how it gets killed after some time and on phone restart. I just want the service:

1. To keep running on phone restart and after long interval of time. In short forever.
2. The tweeting task to continue in case there is a phone restart in between.

So my questions are:

1. How do I create this forever running service? I have searched SO for other similar question and found two solutions-AlarmManager and TimerTask. I am not sure if AlarmManager would keep on starting the service again and again in case it had been killed.I tried TimerTask but it does not resume once the phone reboots. Maybe I could subscribe my service to a system service that would resume it automatically on phone reboot.
2. The thread created for tweeting must not stop if phone is restarted.
3. The service must allow itself to be stopped and resumed with new credentials if the user changes that from the UI.

Also I wanted to know if IntentService would be good for my case or a simple Service would suffice? 
I am comparatively new to Android development and expect the more experienced ones to share their views related to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can certainly subscribe to an event that indicates the phone has booted ([`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)). An `AlarmManager` could also restart the service periodically although don't overdo it. A `TimerTask` won't work as if your application gets killed, there's nothing to run that task.
2. Same thing. Just do this work in the `Service`.

If you have an `IntentService` implementation working, it's not a bad choice as it offloads work off the main thread.